# Saving Variables Prolog

Tags: variables, prolog, save

Is it possible to save variables in Prolog?

I would like to save and edit a list as the program runs but I cannot find anyway of saving the list between edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the Prolog feature you want is assert/retract of a dynamic predicate like **myListVars/1**, which does nothing more than save a specified list of values that you can retrieve subsequently.

For example, if you had three variables `X,Y,Z` that you wanted to memorialize, they could be saved into a dynamic fact **myListXYZ/1** with a predicate like this:

```
setListXYZ(_,_,_) :-
    retract(myListXYZ(_)),
    fail.
setListXYZ(X,Y,Z) :-
    assert(myListXYZ([X,Y,Z])).
```

and retrieved with a predicate like this:

```
getListXYZ(X,Y,Z) :-
    myListXYZ([X,Y,Z]).
```

This approach assumes you will only have (at most) one fact at a time for **myListXYZ/1**, which is guaranteed if one only accesses that predicate through the get/set pair above.

I often use similar "fact" predicates to store test cases for Prolog programs where it is inconvenient to type required arguments in manually.  More than one test case can be accomodated by adding an extra argument that "labels" the test cases.

Comment: I am quite new to Prolog so this may be me making a stupid error, but when I implement your code it returns the error;

'uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,assert/1),setListXYZ/3)'

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, I was missing a closing parenthesis in the second clause of **setListXYZ/3**.  See if what I edited fixes the problem.   Also, what Prolog are you using?

Comment: I had already corrected that, unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.  I'm using The GNU Prolog compiler on Ubuntu.

Comment: I discovered the problem, with GNU you have to use `asserta` or `assertz`to define if you want to add it at the start or end.

Comment: @Jon: Good detective work!  Most Prolog implementations treat `assert` and `assertz` as synonyms.  If there is to be only one such fact asserted, then the ordering at start or end is moot.